# Cumulative abs sums

Tags: combinatorics, sequences-and-series

Let $s$ be an $n$-tuple of reals numbers satisfying $\sum_{k=1}^n s_k$. Denote by $\{c_i\}_{i=1}^n$ the permutations of this tuple $s$.

Consider the tuple $$a_{i,j} = \left\{ \begin{array}{l@{,\quad}l}
                                            |{c_{1,j}}|, &   \\
                                            \max\{a_{i,j-1}-c_{i,j,},0\}, &  j=2,\ldots,n
                \end{array}\right..$$

I'd like to how if there is any property from group theory than can be applied to $a_i$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For $k=1,\ldots,n$ let $p_k=\sum_{i=1}^ks_i$, and fix $k$ such that $p_k$ is minimal; then the true partial sums of $c_{k+1}$ are all non-negative, and hence $a_{k+1,n}=0$. (If $k=n$, $a_{1,n}=0$.)

This is perhaps easiest to see by graphing the partial sums: you’re finding the deepest valley of the original graph and, by shifting the starting point, raising everything by the depth of that valley.

Comment: You missed a shift. It should be $a_{k+1, n}=0$ (unless $k=n$ in which case you're done immediately).

Comment: @Rick: You’re right; I was counting from the $0$-th partial sum.

Comment: @beth_calister: No, I didn’t; I generally prefer to leave a little to be done. Just check that the $i$-th partial sum of $c_{k+1}$ is $p_{k+i}-p_k$, which by the choice of $k$ is non-negative. (If $k+i>n$, replace it by $k+i-n$.) Note that there was still a small indexing error in the version that you read: it should be $c_{k+1}$ (as it now is).

Comment: Ok, now I see. Thanks again! Beth.

Comment: @Beth: You’re welcome!

Comment: @Beth: I finally got back to take a look at that auxiliary question and found that you’d deleted it. If you still want me to take a look and see if I can answer it, I’ll be happy to give it a go. (I have to apologize: I lost track and simply forgot about it.)